# Specify the z-index of Google Map Markers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps

I am having a Google Map with lots of markers added using websockets. I am using custom marker images based on data availability. I want to make sure the newest marker stays on top of all other elements in the map.

How do I do this?

**Code:**

```
circleIcon = {
    path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
    fillColor: "blue",
    fillOpacity: 1,
    scale: 2,
    strokeColor: "red",
    strokeWeight: 10
};

coordinates = image[2].split(',');

pin=new google.maps.LatLng(coordinates[0], coordinates[1]);

if(marker) {
    marker.setMap(null);
}

if(image[0] != "NOP") {
    var markerIcon = circleIcon;
} else {
    var markerIcon = image_car_icon;
}

marker=new google.maps.Marker({
    position:pin,
    icon:markerIcon
});

marker.setMap(map);

map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
```

**Update**

I am using jquery to update the z-index of the InfoWindow, like:

```
popup = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content:'<image id="pin_' + pin_count + '" src="data:image/png;base64,' + image[1] +'"/>',
});

popup.open(map, marker);

google.maps.event.addListener(popup, 'domready', function() {
    console.log("DOM READY...........................");

    // Bring latest Image to top            
    e = $('#pin_' + pin_count).parent().parent().parent().parent();
    e.css({
        'z-index' : 99999 + pin_count,
    });
});
```

Maybe that's why the marker shows behind the InfoWindow. I tried updating using zIndex, but the marker still shows behind the InfoWindow:

```
marker=new google.maps.Marker({
    position:pin,
    zIndex: 9999999 + pin_count,
    icon:markerIcon
});
```

**Update**

Sample code. I expect the "green circle" icon marker to be behind the "pin" icon marker.

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=&sensor=false"></script>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>

    var london = new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742,-0.120850);

    function initialize()
    {
        var pin1=new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742, -0.120850);
        var pin2=new google.maps.LatLng(51.508642, -0.120850);

        var mapProp = {
          center:pin1,
          zoom:17,
          disableDefaultUI:true,
          mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
          };

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);

        var marker=new google.maps.Marker({
          position:pin2,
          zIndex:99999999
          });

        marker.setMap(map);

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
          content:"Hello World!"
          });

         infowindow.open(map,marker);

        circleIcon = {
            path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
            fillColor: "blue",
            fillOpacity: 1,
            scale: 2,
            strokeColor: "green",
            strokeWeight: 10
        };

        var marker2=new google.maps.Marker({
          position:pin1,
          icon:circleIcon,
          zIndex:99999
          });

        marker2.setMap(map);
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="googleMap" style="width:500px;height:380px;"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

---

Comment: have you looked at `MAX_ZINDEX` in the API? SHould be easy to increment it as markers are added  https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Marker

Comment: What about the InfoWindows I may have added? Does MAX_ZINDEX place the marker on top of those too?

Comment: I tried like                marker.setZIndex(google.maps.Marker.MAX_ZINDEX + 1); But even after I set a larger z-index, the value of MAX_ZINDEX is not changing.

Comment: been a while since I worked with API: look at options for markers one is: `zIndex`. Increment that

Comment: @charlietfl It doesn't work. The marker is showing up behind the InfoWIndow.

Comment: I never use InfoWindow, I usually use html overlays which I have more control over. Look through API to see if can get InfoWindow zIndex, or inspect one in browser console

Comment: is stacking order of markers working now for you?

Comment: @charlietfl No, still the second marker shows behind the first.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

By default map will make z-index higher for markers lower on the map so they visibly stack top to bottom

You can set `zIndex` option for a marker. You would just need to create a increment zIndex counter as you add markers and add that to the marker options object:

```
marker=new google.maps.Marker({
    position:pin,
    icon:markerIcon,
    zIndex: counterValue
});
```

I'm not quite sure what the base start value needs to be

Comment: I tried that, didn't work for me... I have updated the question.

Comment: can you create a few markers worth of data and put a demo in jsfiddle.net?

Comment: My whole data is coming from server, so creating a jsfiddle is gonna be tough.

Comment: just something simple with a few markers close enough together to see the issue and code you are using. Only need about 3 or 4 markers

Comment: jsfiddle seems to have some issues, I have added the sample code in the question itself.

Answer (score 60):

You have to set the marker option "optimized" to false in combination with the zIndex option.

```
var marker=new google.maps.Marker({
      position:pin2,
      optimized: false,
      zIndex:99999999
});
```

This should solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the great tip. "optimized: false," is the key.

Comment: zIndex worked for me. didn't need optimized prop. I set zIndex to Date.now() on each iteration, for a group of markers, to keep the last on top.

Comment: That Date.now() suggestion is a great idea. I was looking for a way to make sure a certain infowindow was always on top and this'll certainly do it.

Comment: I required `optimized: false` for all, maybe due to me using some svg icons which require `opmtimized: false`?

Answer (score 4):

Problem solved. Just set the zValue to 999 (I'm guessing higher will bring it more to the top) and it should come to the top. I guess the default is below 999:

```
var zValue;

if (someCondition) {
    zValue = 999;
}

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: {lat: lat, lng: lng},
    title: titleString,
    icon: image,
    zIndex: zValue
});
```

Comment: It will assign 999 to all windows, which won't mean anything.

Answer (score 3):

For existing markers, `marker.setZIndex(value)` must be used. `marker.getZIndex()` can be used to get the current z-index.

Answer (score 1):

Take care that as it says in [the google map documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#CircleOptions) the z-index of a circle will be compared to the z-index of other polygons and not to the z-index of the markers.