# Google Maps v3 move Markers on top when updated

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

My App show couriers on Google Maps and as soon as the application receive a GPS update for one of the courier I keep the Map updated with the new courier position. It happen every second for each of my couriers.

The issue is that every time a courier is updated it is moved on top of all others causing a "disco" effect on the map (because couriers may have differe marker color).

I wish to keep the Marker at the same position (in terms of zIndex or whatever) when its position is updated.

How can I do that?

I don't think any code is required here... I do nothing special than create markers and update markers, but I'm pretty sure a comment will arrive with: "show code", so here we are:

```
funciton createCourierMarkers() {
  var couriersStorage = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < couriers.length; i++) {
    var courier = couriers[i];
    var status = courier.status || 'free';
    var courierPosition = _getCourierPosition(courier);
    var icon = MarkersService.getCourierIcon(status);
    var courierMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      position: courierPosition,
      icon: icon,
      zIndex: 200,
      type: 'courier',
      id: courier.id,
      status: status
    });
    couriersStorage.push(courierMarker);
  }
}

function updateCourierMarkerPosition(courier, marker) {
    var courierPosition = _getCourierPosition(courier);
  marker.setPosition(courierPosition);
}
```

Comment: Assign a zIndex to the courier and set that in the marker or order the couriers and set the zIndex in the marker to be 200 + i. Also from another [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14034292/specify-the-z-index-of-google-map-markers) you might have to set "optimized" to false for zIndex to work

Comment: Increasing by 1 all markers solved my issue. Thanks for the suggestion George. It would be nice to answer properly to the question. Maybe I'm not the one in needs of this kind of answer.